# trying to add 2 char arrays in different objects via operator+ overloading

Tags: c++, arrays, operator-overloading

I seem to be having tons of difficulty getting this addition operator overload to work for my objects. I've scoured the net and can't quite figure out what it is I'm doing wrong. Basically its supposed to be overloaded to concatenate 2 char arrays. Everything I try causes either a crash or a random jumble of characters.

I'm new to operator overloading, so maybe I'm utilizing it wrong.
Its called with:

```
String myString1, myString2; 
std:: cout << "\nYour strings added are: " << myString1 + myString2;
```

And in the header file...

```
 String operator+(String);
```

Here's the relevant code:

```
String String::operator+(String rhs){
String result;
int i = length;

for(int x = 0; x < length; x++)
{
        result.ch[x] = ch[x];
        std::cout << result.ch[x];
}

std:: cout << " ";

for (int j = 0; rhs.ch[j] != '\0'; ++i, ++j)
{
         result.ch[i] = rhs.ch[j];
         std::cout <<result.ch[i];
}

return result;
}
```

I'll provide full source code if needed. Everything else works perfectly though.

.hpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using std::istream;
using std::ostream;

const int default_size = 256;
class String
{

  public:

         // constructors
         String();
         String(const char ch, const int default_size);
         String(const String& rhs, int cap = default_size); // copy constructor

         // accessor functions
         void getLength(String str);
         void outPut(String str); 
         void findChar(String str);
         // destructor
         ~String (); // destructor

         // mutator functions
         void getInput(String str); 

         // friend I/O function overloads
         friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, const String& str);
         friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const String& str);

         // operator overloads
         String operator+(String str);

  private:
          int strLength, length;
          int capacity;
          char ch[default_size];
          char *s; };
```

and .cpp

```
// String.cpp

#include "String.hpp"
#include<iostream>

// default constructor
String::String() 
{
}

// char constructor
String::String(const char ch, const int default_size)
{
capacity = default_size;
s = new char[capacity];
s[0] = ch;
s[1] = '\0';
strLength = 1;
}

//copy constructor
String::String(const String& rhs, const int cap)
{
// Check if string capacity is shorter than length
if (cap <= rhs.strLength)
    capacity = rhs.strLength + 1;
    else
        capacity = cap;

    s = new char[capacity];

// Copy chars to string
for (length = 0; rhs.s[length] != '\0'; ++length)
{
    s[length] = rhs.s[length];
}

s[length] = '\0';
}
// destructor
String::~String()
{
strLength = 0;
delete [] s;
}

// overloaded io operatiors
// Outputs string with << operator
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const String& str)
{
out << str.s;
return out;
}

// Inputs string with >> operator
istream& operator>>(istream& in, const String& str)
{
in >> str.s;
return in;
}

// gets users input
void String::getInput(String str)
{

 std:: cout << "Please enter a string.\n";
 std:: cin.getline(ch, default_size);

}

// getLength
void String:: getLength(String str)
{
  size_t strLength = strlen(str.ch);
  length = strLength;
  std:: cout << "The length is " << strLength << ".\n";
}

// output
void String:: outPut(String str)
{
 std:: cout << "\nYou entered.\n";
 for(int x = 0; x < str.length; x++)
 {
         std:: cout << ch[x];
 }
         std:: cout << "\n";
 }

// user enters a character, this provides the location(s)
void String:: findChar(String str)
{
char * charSearch;
char s;
std:: cout << "\nPlease enter a character to search for. \n";
std:: cin >> s;
std:: cout << "\n";
charSearch = strchr(ch, s);

while(charSearch != '\0')
{
                 std:: cout << "Found at: " << charSearch-ch+1 << "\n" ;
                 charSearch = strchr(charSearch+1, s);
}
std::cin.ignore();
}

// OPERATOR OVERLOADS---------------------------------------------------

// Addition operator 
// adds the right hand object to the lefthand object
String String::operator+(String rhs)
{
String result; 
int i = length;
for(int x = 0; x < length; x++)
{
        result.ch[x] = ch[x];
        std::cout << result.ch[x];
}

std:: cout << " ";

for (int j = 0; rhs.ch[j] != '\0'; ++i, ++j)
{
         result.ch[i] = rhs.ch[j];
         std::cout <<result.ch[i];
}
std::cout << "\nHere is result.ch: ";
for(int z = 0; result.ch[z] != '\0'; z++)
{
        std::cout << result.ch[z];
}

return result;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a custom copy constructor?

Comment: 1. Is `result.ch` big enough for the result? 2. You're not zero-terminating the result. 3. You never set `result.length` to anything reasonable. 4. If `result.ch` is dynamically allocated, you probably have more problems.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still new. ch[] is defaulted to 256, as for the other 3... Suppose I'd best look into them.

Answer (score 0):

You have more problems than the concatenation, and I doubt that everything else "works perfectly".

1. Your default constructor doesn't initialise anything.
   Even `String s; std::cout << s;` shouldn't work, and neither should `String s; std::cin >> s;`.
2. You don't have an assignment operator.
   `{String s1; String s2; s2 = s1;}` will most likely crash.
3. You have both a pointer `s` and an array `ch`.
   You store data in `s`, but some code uses `ch` instead.
   You need to make up your mind.
   (And don't use the same name for parameters and local variables as you do for members.)
4. You have both `strLength` and `length`, and use them seemingly at random.

There's more undefined behaviour in your code than anyone can be bothered to list.
Your best road ahead is probably to throw the code away and start over.